# NetBSD: podman mount volume: Error: statfs : no such file or directory

Tags: podman, netbsd

I'm experimenting with `podman` under NetBSD and want to mount a host directory into the container.

- According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71542236) I did:

  ```shell
  podman machine init -v ~/podman/volumes/:/mnt/podman tpvm
  podman machine start tpvm
  ```
- Now I would expect that

  ```shell
  podman machine ssh tpvm 'ls /mnt'
  ```

  shows me the podman directory, but it did not.
- I continue with:

  ```shell
  podman run -ti --rm -v ~/podman/volumes/:/mnt/podman busybox
  ```

  and I get:

  ```
  Error: statfs /home/thomas/podman/volumes: no such file or directory
  ```
- However:

  ```shell
  ll  /home/thomas/podman/volumes
  total 1.5K
  drwxr-xr-x  3 thomas  users  512B Nov 16 16:20 .
  drwxr-xr-x  4 thomas  users  512B Nov 16 16:20 ..
  drwxr-xr-x  2 thomas  users  512B Nov 17 15:56 posgres
  ```

There is a MAC related thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71977532/5428477), and I also tried [this idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74698541/5428477) but always get the same error.

Any ideas what went wrong?

P.S.: I also checked the output of `--log-level=debug` of the above commands, but got nothing useful for this case.